# NSDictionary using to get key values data in Nsarray

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary

I have some values in Nsarray, using key values (NSDictionary Method) and i need to get that values Show in label separately this is my array values.

```
( "", "user_currency_code=USD", "user_currency_symbol=$", "usertypecode=ROBT", "player_level=1", "player_isblocked=false", "lang=en", "respond=true", "flylogin=false", "str=PageEnd", "user_balance=100000394.90", "user_bonus_balance=0.00", "first_name=test", "cash_balance=100000394.90", "coupon_balance=0.00", "str=PageEnd", "remain_GameCount=0", "remain_PTAmount=0.00", "real_user_balance=100000394.90", "fun_user_balance=95725.15", "user_bonus_balance=0.00", "bonusstatus=false", "bonus_id=null" )
```

Without using  index value i need show the values in label Example dis value`(user_currency_code=USD)` key value is `(user_currency_code) value(USD)` ,so finally USD i need to display in label,like that using key values i will show in label.

Comment: So why aren't you storing these in a dictionary in the first place?

Comment: create a lable using for loop till Nsarray count

Comment: This is not the proper format key-value. NSDictionary reads Key and values.

Answer (score 1):

as per my understanding

```
( "", "user_currency_code=USD", "user_currency_symbol=$", "usertypecode=ROBT", "player_level=1", "player_isblocked=false", "lang=en", "respond=true", "flylogin=false", "str=PageEnd", "user_balance=100000394.90", "user_bonus_balance=0.00", "first_name=test", "cash_balance=100000394.90", "coupon_balance=0.00", "str=PageEnd", "remain_GameCount=0", "remain_PTAmount=0.00", "real_user_balance=100000394.90", "fun_user_balance=95725.15", "user_bonus_balance=0.00", "bonusstatus=false", "bonus_id=null" )
```

it is not look like key value coding. And to get a value from it you need to apply number of check & need to get substring from string to get actual value.  You need to change every key value Like

```
("user_currency_code":"USD")
```

If I did something wrong then let me know

Comment: `("user_currency_code":"USD")` --that is notvalid Objective C syntax to define an NSDictionary in code. You mean something like `@{@"user_currency_code":@"USD"}`

Comment: @mah  Yes,You are Right its like `[data setValue:@"USD" forKey:@"user_currency_code"];`. Actually I had just give a example as JSON keyValue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert this array into a dictionary, as soon as you receive it, and discard the array, as it's useless:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", @"user_ucurrency_code=USD", @"user_currency_symbol=$",
            @"usertypecode=ROBT", @"player_level=1", @"player_isblocked=false", @"lang=en",
            @"respond=true", @"flylogin=false", @"str=PageEnd", @"user_balance=100000394.90",
            @"user_bonus_balance=0.00", @"first_name=test", @"cash_balance=100000394.90",
            @"coupon_balance=0.00", @"str=PageEnd", @"remain_GameCount=0", @"remain_PTAmount=0.00",
            @"real_user_balance=100000394.90", @"fun_user_balance=95725.15", @"user_bonus_balance=0.00",
            @"bonusstatus=false", @"bonus_id=null", nil];

        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        for (NSString *str in arr) {
            NSArray *elements = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            if ([elements count] != 2)
                continue;
            [dict setValue:[elements objectAtIndex:1]
                    forKey:[elements objectAtIndex:0]];
        }

        for (NSString *key in dict) {
            NSLog(@"'%@' = '%@'", key, [dict objectForKey:key]);    // or valueForKey:
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

$ clang -o test test.m -fobjc-arc -framework Foundation
$ ./test
2013-09-02 12:01:53.811 test[51144:707] 'bonusstatus' = 'false'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.836 test[51144:707] 'lang' = 'en'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.837 test[51144:707] 'cash_balance' = '100000394.90'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.837 test[51144:707] 'flylogin' = 'false'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.838 test[51144:707] 'str' = 'PageEnd'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.838 test[51144:707] 'usertypecode' = 'ROBT'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.839 test[51144:707] 'player_isblocked' = 'false'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.839 test[51144:707] 'player_level' = '1'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.839 test[51144:707] 'respond' = 'true'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.840 test[51144:707] 'remain_PTAmount' = '0.00'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.840 test[51144:707] 'fun_user_balance' = '95725.15'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.841 test[51144:707] 'remain_GameCount' = '0'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.841 test[51144:707] 'user_balance' = '100000394.90'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.842 test[51144:707] 'user_currency_symbol' = '$'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.842 test[51144:707] 'bonus_id' = 'null'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.842 test[51144:707] 'coupon_balance' = '0.00'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.843 test[51144:707] 'real_user_balance' = '100000394.90'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.843 test[51144:707] 'user_bonus_balance' = '0.00'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.848 test[51144:707] 'first_name' = 'test'
2013-09-02 12:01:53.871 test[51144:707] 'user_ucurrency_code' = 'USD'
```

Answer (score 0):

First you array with dictionary Look like this:-

```
(
        {
        "player_isblocked" = false;
        "player_level" = 1;
        "user_currency_code" = USD;
        "user_currency_symbol" = "$";
        usertypecode = ROBT;
    }
}
```

i Test it using this code:-

```
 NSMutableArray *ar=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

     NSMutableDictionary *dOfPerson=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    [dOfPerson setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"USD"] forKey:@"user_currency_code"];
    [dOfPerson setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$"] forKey:@"user_currency_symbol"];
    [dOfPerson setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ROBT"] forKey:@"usertypecode"];
    [dOfPerson setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"1"] forKey:@"player_level"];
    [dOfPerson setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"false"] forKey:@"player_isblocked"];


    [ar addObject:dOfPerson];

    NSLog(@"ar === %@",ar);
```

Then you have to show this using this example:-

```
yourString= [[yourArray objectAtIndex:0(here is item of index)]objectForKey:@"user_currency_code"];// user_currency_code you have write your want key



NSLog(@"%@ =====",[[ar objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"user_currency_code"]);
```

OUTPUT IS:-

```
USD
```

**OR your can also like bellow Way**

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in yourArray) {

// here you get with dic all value here try with nslog like
 NSLog(@"%@ =====",[dict valueForKey:@"yourKey");//your is is user_currency_code,user_currency_symbol etc
}
```

Comment: I don't see how that will work, what is the effect of calling `[NSString valueForKey:]`?

Comment: @NitinGohel I also don't see how it could work, since he isn't actually storing an NSDictionary in each index... just a string (and not even an NSString). Unless the C string pattern "key=value" magically transforms to an NSDictionary, you're assuming something the poster said is not the case.

Comment: @trojanfoe and mah now i can update my answer hope this is right now and thx for correct  me